# なってしまいました conjugation

Tags: contractions, subsidiary-verbs

So I was talking to this girl and she sent me this message:

> あたしもラーメン食べたくなっちゃったw

(She always send me the same message in English, which I got admit that makes my life easier)

Since I was not understanding the sentence in Japanese I asked her to send me it without any abbreviation, then she sent me:

> 食べたくなってしまいました

I guess it is 食べたい + なる + ??? I don't get the shimaimashita (shima + imasu in the past tense?)

And how could she compress all that with only ちゃった？ Isn't ちゃ supposed to only compress ては？

Comment: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/unintended.html#part2 i've found an useful link about it aswell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「食{た}べたくなってしまいました」

is composed of:

> 「食べる + たい + なる + しまう + ます in past tense」

As far as meaning,

「食べたくなってしまいました」＝

「食べたくなってしまった」＝

「食べたくなっちゃいました」＝

「食べたくなっちゃった」

Those were listed in the order of formality and politeness.  Now what do they mean?  Here are my personal best:

> 「あたしもラーメン食べたくなっちゃった。」 means:
>
> "I've got the urge to eat ramen (suddenly) myself."
>
> "It/You got me craving ramen!"

Finally,

> Isn't ちゃ supposed to only compress ては？

You are clearly thinking of a different kind of 「ては」 here.  For instance:

「行{い}っ**ては**ダメ！」＝「行っ**ちゃ**だめ！」＝ "Don't go!"

The 「ちゃ」 that we are discussing here is just part of 「ちゃう」, which is the colloquial form of 「てしまう」.

Comment: it makes sense, that's the first time i've ever heard about しまいます Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed 食べたい + なる  + しまう. しまう means to do all the way or to "accidentally" do. So it's: want to eat + become + by accident. Or something like "I accidentally got hungry".

ちゃう or じゃう is short for てしまう or でしまう respectively. not sure what you mean by ては

Comment: I meant that 全部食べてはだめ could become 全部食べちゃ cha in this case is abbreviating  te wa and then omitting dame or am I mistaken? I'm not sure

Comment: "Accidentally" is not the best word here perhaps. Isn't it closer to "damn, now I want to eat ramen too lol"? Like, she is somewhat troubled by this feeling.

Comment: Just to add some context, I had ramen for lunch and sent her the picture and this was her response. You make sense!